# HttpListner not listening

Tags: c#, httplistener

I am trying to check if there is an ajax request to a particular url and if yes, then I am trying to add a cookie to the request.

But my HttpListner is listening only for `localhost`. If I try to give any other url, it is not listening.

I have turned off my firewall also but still the same issue.

Please tell me where I am making a mistake.

Below is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listner = new HttpListener();
        listner.Prefixes.Add("<my url>");//For example, https://www.google.co.in/
        listner.Start();
        HttpListenerContext context = listner.GetContext();

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        WebRequest webReq = WebRequest.Create(request.Url);

        //Copying the headers
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers = request.Headers;
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.AllKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(headers.AllKeys[i]))
            {
                webReq.Headers.Add(headers.AllKeys[i], headers[headers.AllKeys[i]]);
            }
        }

        webReq.ContentLength = request.ContentLength64;
        webReq.ContentType = request.ContentType;
        webReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "<My Cookie>");


        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        WebResponse webResponse = webReq.GetResponse();
        webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(response.OutputStream);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that httplistener is for making web servers and the like.  Setting the url to google would mean "I want to handle web requests coming in to google" which isn't going to happen.  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: When I am trying to send a cross-origin request using $.ajax , the browser is removing the cookies which authenticates the request. So I am writing a proxy which will intercept the request, add the header and then sends it.

Comment: I want to handle web requests which are going to google (example) from my machine

Comment: I think  you are trying to solve a problem that has already been solved: https://quickleft.com/blog/cookies-with-my-cors/

Comment: It is somewhat like fiddler. Fiddler is able to listen to any request I am making from my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever prefixes you add to the listener HAVE to resolve to your localhost machine. Make sure that your DNS server correctly resolves the host to the machine where you run your code.

If you are testing this in a development environment and/or don't have control over the DNS server, add an entry to the hosts file that maps whatever host name you want to use to your local machine.

The other thing to watch out for is the port. Make sure nothing else is listening on the port you intend to use.

Comment: does it mean that if I am listening for "https://google.com/", the listener will not fire ?

Comment: You need to understand how a host name is resolved. You can override DNS resolution by adding an entry in your local Hosts file that points the domain Google.com to your local machine. Only then will the requests by routed to your local listener. Take moment to read this: https://www.verisign.com/en_US/website-presence/online/how-dns-works/index.xhtml

Comment: Read this too: http://www.lifeasasysadmin.com/how-to-use-hosts-file-to-override-dns-for-local-testing/